# Artificial intelligence and undecidibility

Tags: undecidability, artificial-intelligence

Can artificial intelligence solve problems like Post correspondence problem?

Comment: You should as well go through the community guidelines/help Centre,for future use.

Answer (score 6):

No.  The Post correspondence problem is undecidable.  That means that no computer program can solve it (in all cases).  "Artificial intelligence" is just a computer program. Actually, "artificial intelligence" is a name for something that we're not even sure how to do with a computer program; but even if we knew how to achieve it, it would still be a computer program.  Artificial intelligence isn't magic -- anything that can be done is still constrained by the laws of physics and mathematics.

Comment: We need some facts to prove this!

Comment: And if you accept the Church-Turing thesis, no human can solve it in all cases either!

Comment: @quintumnia all arguments made by D.W. are easily verifiable, if not already considered 'common knowledge' with respect to our community